# Do I need I license to have these walkie talkies in Japan

Tags: legal, license, ht, japan

I currently reside in Japan (not on a military base) and I have been interested in purchasing some walkie talkies. I found these on amazon JP
[Link](http://www.amazon.co.jp/F-R-C-EXPLORER-%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9-%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E5%B0%8F%E9%9B%BB%E5%8A%9B%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC2%E5%8F%B0%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%83%88-ET-20X/dp/B001238SDU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1460893425&sr=8-1&keywords=walkie%20talkie) and I was wondering if can I own something like this without a license. Here are the specs.

```
Transmission and reception frequency: 422.050 ~ 422.300MHz (12.5KHz step) 

Types of radio wave: F3E

Transmission output: 10mW 

Receiving sensitivity: -14dBμ following (12dB SINAD)

Receiving system: double superheterodyne system

Power supply voltage: DC3.6 ~ 4.5V (AA alkaline batteries × 3 This optional)

Current consumption receiving standby time of about 50mA receive a maximum time of about 140mA during transmission about 70mA
```

I assumed that since it was on Amazon Jp that it must be legal in Japan but I thought that I should be safe than sorry. So are these walkie talkies legal and if they are would I need a license? Also do these seem like good quality walkie talkies? Would they have a good range (i.e. a few miles). I couldn't find and info about the distance on that amazon page.

Comment: Please include the model and specifications of what you are asking about. Your question should remain useful even if the listing on Amazon is removed. And you ought to consider asking the core “can I own something like this without a license” part from questions about specific models, because even though this is not strictly a duplicate of [your previous question](http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/are-these-walkie-talkies-legal-in-japan), it's not very useful to anyone to ask the same thing about many different models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_radio_service#Japan

> In Japan, a similar service is limited to 10 milliwatts in the 420, 421,   and 422 MHz bands.It is called "Tokutei Shoudenryoku Musen" ("SLPR:Specified Low Power Radio").
>
> 422.0500–422.1750 MHz (Business use) 10 mW 11ch 12.5 kHz spacing.
>
> 422.200–422.300 MHz (Leisure use) 10 mW 9 channels 12 kHz spacing.

Looks pretty legal to me. Enjoy! (There are also similar bands around globe, but because the Radio Frequencies World is divided into regions, there are different bands used in Europe or North America with different power and sometimes other legal constraints.)

Comment: LOL... 10mW... if you shout really loud, you get more coverage!!

(sorry; couldn't resist...)